# How to Disable TLS 1.0 and 1.1 to enable only TLS 1.2 in Apache 2.4.10 & openssl 1.0.2k fips & RHEL 7

Tags: ssl, apache-2.4, openssl, rhel7

Tried to enable TLS 1.2 in /conf/extra/httpd-ssl.conf in Apache 2.4.10 as below combinations.

SSLProtocol -all +TLSv1.2

After restarting httpd service, getting error 'illegal Protocol TLSv1.2' as below.
AH00526: Syntax error on line 260 of /opt/NSAx/apache2.4-npservers/conf/extra/httpd-ssl.conf:
SSLProtocol: Illegal protocol 'TLSv1.2'

Then updated SSLProtocol in http-ssl.conf file.
SSLProtocol -SSLv3 -TLSv1 -TLSv1.1 +TLSv1.2

After restarting httpd service, getting error 'illegal Protocol TLSv1.1' as below.
AH00526: Syntax error on line 260 of /opt/NSAx/apache2.4-npservers/conf/extra/httpd-ssl.conf:
SSLProtocol: Illegal protocol 'TLSv1.1'

Set this SSLHonorCipherOrder in httpd-ssl.conf file both on / off.  still same error.
SSLHonorCipherOrder     off

Also tried different set of SSLCipersuite from [https://ssl-config.mozilla.org/#server=apache&version=2.4.10&config=intermediate&openssl=1.0.2k-fips&guideline=5.6][1]

ran command 'nmap --script ssl-enum-ciphers -p 443 hostname' in linux and returned SSLv3, TLSv1.0 enabled.

Hope, mentioned version of OpenSSL, Apache & Linux OS will support TLS 1.2.
Please help me, why does this configuration cause 'illegal protocol' error and How can I enable TLS 1.2 only with this setup?

Really Appreciate, if any help.

Comment: Where did you get this strange build of Apache?

Comment: When I ran httpd -v command in linux, got Server version: Apache/2.4.10 (Unix) & Server built:   Apr 13 2016 03:34:11.

Comment: Yes, but where did it come from?

Comment: Thanks for response! They installed apache 2.4.10 version long back it seems. I just got a chance to work on TLS protocol validation alone. Could you please recommend configurations?

Comment: Apache uses openssl, so whatever your openssl libraries support, will be supported by Apache. I'd recommend getting a newer version or compile yourself with modern openssl libs.

Comment: https://www.techpond.in/how-disable-tls-10-tls-11-linux-apache-servers